# How to gray-out/have invisible elements with PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm writing a interface with PySide and I want some elements of the interface to be grayed-out/invisible/unaccessible until another action has been performed(no sense in counting the words in a file until the file has been loade for example) I'm thinking this should be possible but I can't seem to find how.

For example, I create this menu:

```
        # We create the actions for the edit menu

        countAction = QtGui.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('exit.png'), '&Count', self)
        countAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+C')
        countAction.setStatusTip('Counts the points in the current point cloud')
        #openAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        # We create the menus       

        editMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&Edit')

        # We add the actions to the edit menu
        editMenu.addAction(countAction)
```

How do I make this menu, and later on buttons and text field, unaccesable until a certain event( loading of a file) has occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many objects in Qt can be grayed out using `setEnabled(False)` and re-enabled using `setEnabled(True)`. Apply it to QAction.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was something simple I was overlooking.